# MySQL query for same field multiple time in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to use same field multiple times. I tired one query but am not getting correct result.

this is my database structure:

**wp_postmeta:**

[image]

**wp_posts:**
[image]

Here this is my query:

```
SELECT wp.ID FROM wp_postmeta wpm 
LEFT JOIN 
wp_posts wp ON (wp.ID = wpm.post_id) 
WHERE  
wp.post_parent=7886 AND 
wpm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_size' AND 
wpm.meta_value="l" AND 
wpm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse' AND 
wpm.meta_value="no"
```

> here i want to get result `ID 7951`.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: @Sadikhasan: `ID 7951` is a correct result. But this query shows empty value

Comment: @RameshS: What is your current result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some kind of aggregation here to isolate the keys and values in the meta table.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT wp.ID
FROM wp_postmeta wpm 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp
    ON wp.ID = wpm.post_id
WHERE  
    wp.post_parent = 7886
GROUP BY
    wp.ID
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_size'
             THEN wpm.meta_value END) = 'l' AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN wpm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse'
             THEN wpm.meta_value END) = 'no';
```

To see how the above pivot trick works, consider the following (single) table of keys and values:

```
ID | meta_key                           | meta_value
1  | attribute_pa_size                  | l
1  | attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse | no
2  | attribute_pa_size                  | l
2  | attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse | yes
```

By aggregating on `ID`, we can tease out the values for any key we want.  For example, to check the value for the `attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse` key we can use:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'attribute_pa_with-bro-kalam-blouse'
         THEN meta_value END)
```

This works because the values being evaluated by `MAX` are either `NULL`, when a row does not have the right key, or is the `meta_value` when the key does match.  Note that `MAX` (and most of the aggregate functions) ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you it working can you please explain what is `MAX(CASE`? why want to use this?

Comment: Yeah sure. And  are you CEO of CabFair?

Comment: I am CEO of many things, including my gym bag, shower, and laptop.  Titles can be misleading.